# Denormalize Map type

Tags: apache-spark

Given this collection :

```
("user1",Map("Gobelin" -> "2","Archers" ->"3"))
("user2",Map("Giant" -> "1"))
```

I want an output that looks like this

```
("user1","Gobelin","2")
("user1","Archers","3")
("user2","Giant","1")
```

How can I acheive this with Spark?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're looking for `flatMapValues`:

```scala
val rdd  = sc.parallelize(
  ("user1",Map("Gobelin" -> "2","Archers" ->"3")) :: 
  ("user2",Map("Giant" -> "1")) :: Nil)

rdd.flatMapValues(identity[Map[String, String]])
```

or `explode`:

```scala
rdd.toDF.select($"_1", explode($"_2")).as[(String, String, String)].rdd
```